# Regular Expression - Python - Remove Leading Whitespace

Tags: python, regex

I search a text file for the word Offering with a regular expression. I then use the start and end points from that search to look down the column and pull the integers. Some instances (column A) have leading white-space I do not want. I want to print just the number (as would be found in Column B) into a file, no leading white-space. Regex in a regex? Conditional?

```
price = re.search(r'(^|\s)off(er(ing)?)?', line, re.I)
if price:
    ps = price.start()
    pe = price.end()

             A             B
           Offering       Offer
            56.00         55.00 
            45.00         45.55
            65.222        32.00
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`strip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove leading and trailing whitespaces:

```
In [1]: ' 56.00  '.strip()
Out[1]: '56.00'
```

Comment: In the context of the regex result? I cannot .strip() the whole text file.

Comment: @CaptainCretaceous: You'll have to read it line by line (sorry, I thought that part was sufficiently obvious) and for each line do `line[ps:pe].strip()`

Answer (score 2):

'^\s+|\s+$'

Use this to regular expression access leading and trailing whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove only the leading white spaces using regular expressions, you can use re.sub to do that.

```
>>> import re
>>>re.sub(r"^\s+" , "" , "  56.45")
'56.45'
```