# Regex for extracting all complex dates formats from a string in python

Tags: python, regex, date

I have following string:

```
 dateEntries = "04-20-2009; 04/20/09; 4/20/09; 4/3/09; Mar 20, 2009; March 20, 2009; Mar. 20, 2009; Mar 20 2009; 20 Mar 2009; 20 March 2009; 2 Mar. 2009; 20 March, 2009; Mar 20th, 2009; Mar 21st, 2009; Mar 22nd, 2009; Feb 2009; Sep 2009; Oct 2010; 6/2008; 12/2009; 2009; 2010"
```

Here I want to extract all mentioned dates using `regex`. As an attempt I have written following `regex`:

```
import re

regEx = r'(?:\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd\s]*)?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z\s,.]*(?:\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd)\s,]*)?(?:\d{2,4})'

re.findall(regEx, dateEntries)
```

I was expecting this to work but it only return subset of dates.

```
A = ['Mar 20, 2009',
 'March 20, 2009',
 'Mar. 20, 2009',
 'Mar 20 2009',
 '20 Mar 2009',
 '20 March 2009',
 '2 Mar. 2009',
 '20 March, 2009',
 'Mar 20th, 2009',
 'Mar 21st, 2009',
 'Mar 22nd, 2009',
 'Feb 2009',
 'Sep 2009',
 'Oct 2010']
```

I'm not getting why its not returning the dates:

```
B=[04-20-2009; 04/20/09; 4/20/09; 4/3/09; 6/2008; 12/2009; 2009; 2010"]
```

I created the `regEx` by extending the `r'(?:\d{1,2}[-\s\/])?(?:\d{1,2}[-\/\s])?(?:\d{2,4})'` which works good for set B. But `regEx` is not able to produce `A+B`

Can anyone help in making a regex for extracting all dates mentioned in my `dateEntries` ?

**NOTE:** I want to solve this using regex only.

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex? For your example you could just use dateEntries.split(";").

Comment: Because my real data has text file in which set `A` categories dates are possible, and text file has other data apart from dates.

Comment: FYI [] matches single characters and character ranges, not strings like th or st. You should replace with ()

Comment: Your second non-capturing group should probably be optional

Comment: Try `(?:[\s]?\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd\s]*)?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)?[a-z\s,./]*(?:\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd)\s,]*)?(?:\d{2,4})`  [here](https://regex101.com/r/DaeLCX/1)

Answer (score 7):

You are just missing a single `?` after the `(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)` group to mark it as not necessary. Additionally I added a `+` behind the last two groups to make sure the regex doesn't split dates like "20 March 2009" into two different dates.

The full code:

```
import re

regEx = r'(?:\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd\s]*)?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)?[a-z\s,.]*(?:\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd)\s,]*)+(?:\d{2,4})+'

dateEntries = "04-20-2009; 04/20/09; 4/20/09; 4/3/09; Mar 20, 2009; March 20, 2009; Mar. 20, 2009; Mar 20 2009; 20 Mar 2009; 20 March 2009; 2 Mar. 2009; 20 March, 2009; Mar 20th, 2009; Mar 21st, 2009; Mar 22nd, 2009; Feb 2009; Sep 2009; Oct 2010; 6/2008; 12/2009; 2009; 2010"
result = re.findall(regEx, dateEntries)
print(result)
```

If your date has leading whitespaces, the result will also have leading whitespaces. If you continue using the date string you could remove them for example [with the `.strip()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518172/regular-expression-python-remove-leading-whitespace)

Comment: Thanks @Nils. I'm also able to extract using this regex `r'(?:\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd\s.])?(?:(?:Jan|January|Feb|February|Mar|March|Apr|April|May|Jun|June|Jul|July|August|Sep|September|Oct|October|Nov|November|Dec|December)[\s,.]*)?(?:(?:\d{1,2})[-/th|st|nd|rd\s,.]*)?(?:\d{2,4})'`

Comment: How to capture this format? 2020 January 1
2020 January 01 ; 2020 Jan. 1 ; 2020 Jan. 01 ; 2020 JAN. 1 ; 2020 JAN. 01

Answer (score 2):

Your regex pattern is totally unreadable.. Please build your regex pattern with simple building blocks. That would make the code a lot more readable

```
import re
import calendar

full_months = [month for month in calendar.month_name if month]
short_months = [d[:3] for d in full_months]
months = '|'.join(short_months + full_months)

sep = r'[.,]?\s+'               # seperator
day = r'\d+'
year = r'\d+'
day_or_year = r'\d+(?:\w+)?'

r = re.compile(rf'(?:{day}{sep})?(?:{months}){sep}{day_or_year}(?:{sep}{year})?')
r.findall(dateEntries)
# ['Mar 20, 2009', 'March 20, 2009', 'Mar. 20, 2009', 'Mar 20 2009', '20 Mar 2009', '20 March 2009', '2 Mar. 2009', '20 March, 2009', 'Mar 20th, 2009', 'Mar 21st, 2009', 'Mar 22nd, 2009', 'Feb 2009', 'Sep 2009', 'Oct 2010']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex:

`^(?:\d{1,2}(?:(?:-|/)|(?:th|st|nd|rd)?\s))?(?:(?:(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)(?:(?:-|/)|(?:,|\.)?\s)?)?(?:\d{1,2}(?:(?:-|/)|(?:th|st|nd|rd)?\s))?)(?:\d{2,4})$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BkIDCM/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regex

```
(?:\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd\s]*)?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)?[a-z\s,.]*(?:\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd)\s,]*)+(?:\d{2,4})+
```